# high availability cluster on NetBSD?

Tags: cluster-computing, high-availability, netbsd

I need to set up a High Availability cluster using NetBSD. 
Previously i have set up a cluster on RedHat machines using RedHat Cluster Suite. Similarly under the UNIX environment of NetBSD what will i use to start a cluster ?

Answer (score 2):

A setup using the Common Address Redundancy Protocol (CARP) might be a good place to start:

http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-carp.html

It can be used for a number of things including failover and load-balancing.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get heartbeat 2.1 working on NetBSD with only a few changes to the code and to the resource agents.

Also, I started porting the Corosync/Pacemaker stack to NetBSD, but that is not working yet. There is still a fix required for libqb (in terms of socket operations).

See:
http://lists.corosync.org/pipermail/discuss/2012-December/002259.html
http://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-users/2012/12/12/msg012160.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a failover cluster manager in shell script and even if I didn't yet
tested it on netbsd it works on OpenBSD/FreeBSD. there are high chances that
it just work out of the box on netbsd. still you will need to script  a little
to handle the resources you want to move in your high availability cluster,
for example handling fencing if needed. 
my program is called back-to-work and you can download it here:
https://sites.google.com/site/shellclustersuite/